# animating SVG path when changing value

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a graph using SVG and angular directive to change the dynamic parts. Right now I've done this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TcbK7kyzM3tapDISxndh?p=preview

```
app.directive('pieChart', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<svg width="500" height="500">' +
          '<path d="M100,200 a150,150 0 1,0 150,-150" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path>' +
        '</svg>',
        scope: {
          value: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        }
    }
});
```

I want my graph to look like this when it's 100% value, and when the value is -- let's say -- 45%, I would like to see this line but with only 45% of it's length from the top center. I probably have to re-calculate the path value of the path but I wanted to ask, is it possible when I change the path with JS to make it animate while it's changing the size?

Thank you in advance, or if any of you know a good tutorial on this stuff please link it to me.

EDIT: I changed the directive to a simple bar graph but this is just for example, I know this can be done without SVG since you can make it using divs but i want the chart to be more complex after.

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fg9e7eo4/1/

In my example, the chart keeps animating and I would like to make it animate only once and than remain at that point.

By the way, this is the directive that I'm trying out to make it work:

```
testApp.directive('pieChart', function() {
  var html = 
    '<svg width="510" height="20" style="background: #fff">' +
      '<path d="{{path}}" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="none">' +
        '<animate dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" values="{{path2}}"/>' +
      '</path>' +
    '</svg>';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: html,
    scope: {
      'value': '='
    },

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        scope.path = 'M 5 10, L ' + (newValue * 5) + ' 10';
        scope.path2 = 'M 5 10, L ' + (oldValue * 5) + ' 10; M 5 10, L ' + (newValue * 5) + ' 10';
        elem.children().children().beginElement();
      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You need to $observe the value of the attr

Comment: i get the value updated by the scope i called inside the directive but i dont know when i change the path inside the template, how to animate the path from the last 'd' to the new one

Comment: You will essentially have to modify the path in intervals using some easing function. There are frameworks (like snap or d3) that can do this for you - [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/31ec1817b2be2660c453) is an example using d3.

Comment: i understand that you can also do animations with something called SMIL.. is it posible to do it without js ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use bar chart, why don't you use `rect` instead of `path`?
IMO, `rect` is more descriptive than `path`.

Here is my example to use `rect` to animate it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2hEzBqIVgh0rgE3D0Pd4?p=preview

For AngularJS, you simply set `width` and `to` attribute.

```
<rect x="10" y="10" height="110" width="500"
     style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff">
    <animate
        attributeName="width"
        begin="0s"
        dur="2s"
        from="0"
        to="500"
    />
</rect>
```

This answer is also helpful, I think.
[SMIL animation on SVG ng-repeat'ed element only occurs on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614750/smil-animation-on-svg-ng-repeated-element-only-occurs-on-page-load)

Comment: i appreciate your response but i was searching a way to start / stop the animation via angular directive, is there a way to hook the start / stop of the animation with a function inside the directive? so i can call it when the model changes

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel, I might be wrong, but I do not see your question as stop/start SVG animation. I have my own answer for that, but let's not get readers confused. I would recommend you to post another question, and let me know, I will gladly answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to animate only once and then stop replace repeatCount="indefinite" by repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"

If you make sure the paths in the values are consistent in the numbers and types of command you should get smooth animation. Here's an example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500">
    <path d="M100,200 L150,200" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" fill="none">
        <animate attributeName="d" values="M100,200 L150,200;M100,200 L200, 200" fill="freeze" begin="1s" dur="2s" />
    </path>
</svg>
```

The SVG testsuite has [an example of path animation.](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/animate-elem-44-t.html) and there's a [w3c primer on animation](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations).

Comment: yep, i tested it in jsfiddle but the animation doesnt work anymore

Comment: Unless you show me the updated fiddle I can't see what you've done wrong. And does "doesn't work any more" mean it isn't smooth or it does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're up for trying new plugins, but from the looks of [Easy Pie Chart.js](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/) has what you want, it's real quick to configure and pretty lightweight. If you're set on using SVGs have a look at [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/), I know for a fact you can animate SVGs (and even morph from one to another).

Hopefully this helps!